# Uploading an array of images using AFNetworking 2 Batch requests

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have an array of images that I'm trying to upload to a server using AFNetworking batch request.  Here is my code, I'm getting an error and I'm not sure why

```
-(void)imageUploader {


    NSArray *imageArray = _listing.productImageArray;


    imageCounter = 1;

    NSString * ts = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate new] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
    NSMutableArray *mutableOperations = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSURL *fileURL in imageArray) {

        imagesUploaded = 0;

        NSString *counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", imageCounter];


        NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"https://myayla.com/bl/saveProductImages.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"images[]" error:nil];
        } error:nil];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [mutableOperations addObject:operation];
    }

    NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        NSLog(@"All operations in batch complete");
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

here is the error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImage lastPathComponent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Can anyone help out? Thanks

Comment: Is `imageArray` definitely an array of URL's? Somewhere, someone's expecting a string, but they're getting an image. Based on:` lastPathComponent` (a NSString method) being called on a UIImage.

Comment: You were right... It wasn't an array of URL's,  I changed my code to reflect the images and it works great..  Make an answer and I'll accept.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is imageArray definitely an array of URL's? Somewhere, someone's expecting a string, but they're getting an image. Based on:`lastPathComponent` (a NSString method) being called on a UIImage.